Is my meander a bad idea?
Autodesk Eagle's Meander:

My compact meander:

How bad of an idea is it to use "My compact meander" meander instead of the Eagles's version? The Autodesk Eagle's meander tool is very bad, takes up a lot of space, and does not quite understand my feelings. It's a lot more efficient to do it manually. I have an intuition that "My compact meander" is a bad idea as it would make a low-inductance path and effectively short the signal in high frequency AC domain, or maybe cause reflections.
Use Case: I am trying to connect an LPDDR4 memory to TI's Sitara AM6442. I know Altium is the better way to do it, but it has a steeper learning curve, way too sophisticated for simpler things. I personally am able to do the do the same task faster on Eagle than on Altium. (I myself cannot believe I am priasing Autodesk's software, but then Eagle was not made by Autodesk ;P)
Thanks,
Yours Truly
EDIT: Please ignore the track spacing, this is for demonstration only.

On the first glance it will mess up the cross-coupling at the very least

It depends on signal speed and type. LPDDR4 sounds "fast" but which wire that is, and is it differential or single-ended?

I was hoping to do it for all important signals like Address and Data, lets say we do it for for just single ended, would that work?

Each one gives you different characteristics but in short:
Accordion has more capacitance between traces because of the short runs. You can actually run into situations where you get signals shooting through the capacitance and arriving sooner than you would think.
Trombone has more cross coupling between traces and more inductance which can slow the signal down and cause issues by smoothing out rise times.
You need to provide a certain line with spacing to avoid crosstalk (depending on speed for 1.6GHz 15mil spacing between accordion traces works for me). It looks like the above trombone is too closely spaced, you will get massive amounts of crosstalk if you get closer than 5mil at ~1GHz+ speeds.
I prefer using accordion with proper spacing, 15mil is better, but if things are tight and it's a short accordion with only a few meanders you can go smaller down to say 10mil.
This topic is very complex it as you can see in this 1hr video

You mention spacing in the trombone case, but not about accordions; should we take this to mean it possible that they have higher coupling capacitance regardless of distance? If not, perhaps distance and coupling should be mentioned, perhaps in the same manner, there as well?

I saw the video, very informative, ill mark this answer as the solution, as the video addresses a lot of my doubts on the topic

According to an Altium length matching article, for high speed single ended buses like DDR you should use accordion length matching instead of trombone which is suitable for lower speeds.
So purely based on this source, yes the idea of using trombone length matching for a high speed bus is not a good idea.
Everything is relative though. You might be able to achieve an acceptable solution even with trombones.
Besides no matter what method you use, you need to design the parameters correctly to have proper trace impedance without too much impedance discontinuities and mismatches.
